# "Rotating" a value of a string variable

Tags: c#, .net, windows, rotation

How can I "rotate" the value of a string variable?
For example, if I have a string variable called x, which value is "ABCD", how can i "rotate" it to: "DABC" (moving each letter one step forward and bringing the last letter to the first place), how can I do it?

Comment: Homework????????. Did you try anything ?

Comment: implement it using stack ;) ?

Comment: *Rotate* means take a last letter and put it at the beginning. Create a new string which consist of last character in the string plus original string without last character. At which point you have problem?

Answer (score 1):

Declare a char variable, store the value at the last index of the string. Then, starting from the second last index, move each character to it's adjacent position. Go on till you hit the beginning. In the end, just place the value in the character declared before into the first index. I won't give you the code, try it yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Because I love one liners, and taking advantage of a string being an enumerable of char

```
    string x = "ABCD";
    string x2 = new string((x.Skip(x.Length - 1).Concat(x.Take(x.Length - 1))).ToArray());
```

(x.Skip(x.Length - 1) instead of something like x.Last() or x[x.Length-1] to keep it enumerable for the concat )

Comment: Good luck OP if you try turning this in as your homework. You better be prepared to explain this code.